# How to draw a Rectangle in Qgraphicsview dynamically (runtime), using Qt4

Tags: c++, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qmouseevent

using QT Creator version 2.4.1.

I'm just a starter on QT platform and trying to draw a Rectangle Dynamically. The program uses 3 Mouse events namely

- mousePressEvent
- mouseMoveEvent
- mouseReleaseEvent

Problems is **mouseMoveEvent** is never called.

Here is the code snippet

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "mysquare.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setMouseTracking(true);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
    square = new mySquare;
    scene->addItem(square);
    square->mPix = QPixmap(200,200);
    square->mPix.fill(Qt::white);
    scene->addPixmap(square->mPix);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    square->selectedTool = 1;
}
```

**Dialog.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include "mysquare.h"

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    mySquare *square;

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**mysquare.cpp**

```
#include "mysquare.h"

using namespace std;


mySquare::mySquare()
{
    pressed  = false;
    selectedTool = 1;
    mPix = QPixmap(200,200);
    mPix.fill(Qt::white);
}

void mySquare::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->begin(this);
    if(pressed)
    {
        painter->drawPixmap(0,0,mPix);
        painter->drawRect(mRect);
        drawStarted = true;
    }
    else if (drawStarted)
    {
        QPainter tempPainter(&mPix);
        tempPainter.drawRect(mRect);
        painter->drawPixmap(0,0,mPix);
    }

    painter->end();
}

void mySquare::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressed = true;

    y = event->pos();
    cout<<"Pos X : "<<y.x() <<endl;
    cout<<"Pos Y : "<<y.y() <<endl;

    if(selectedTool == 1)
    {
        mRect.setTopLeft(event->pos());
        mRect.setBottomRight(event->pos());

        cout << "Value of x_start axis " << X_1 <<endl;
        cout << "Value of y_start axis " << Y_1 <<endl;
    }
    else if (selectedTool == 2)
    {

    }
    update();
}

void mySquare::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    cout<<"Inside mouseMoveEvent \n";
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        if(selectedTool == 1){
            mRect.setBottomRight(event->pos());
        }
        else if (selectedTool == 2){
            //mLine.setP2(event->pos());
        }
    }
    update();
}

void mySquare::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressed = false;
    update();
    cout<<"Inside mouseReleaseEvent \n";
}
```

**mysquare.h**

```
#ifndef MYSQUARE_H
#define MYSQUARE_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
#include <iostream>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

class mySquare: public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    mySquare();
    int selectedTool;
    QPixmap mPix;
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    bool pressed;
    bool drawStarted;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

private:
    QRectF mRect;
    QPointF y;


private slots:

};

#endif // MYSQUARE_H
```

Please guide me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting property `mouseTracking` to true.
[You can read it here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)

Also you have some problems in your code.
For example you creating `mySquare` object using `square = new mySquare;`. But i can't see code where you call `delete square`.

Comment: Hi, you should comment on the question if you need clarifications. Since you don't have the reputation to comment, you should avoid asking for clarifications or details by posting an answer.

Comment: setMouseTracking event is set true in dialog.cpp. i have edited the code accordingly. But the problems seems to not end here. My concept of this program was to draw a rectangle dinamically, all the 3 mouse events are working but on the ui no rectangle is drawn.